# What are directives? dojo dstore

Tags: dojo

What is the second parameter {directives} for methods put and add?
Does anyone know what you can put here?

https://github.com/SitePen/dstore/blob/master/docs/Store.md

```
put(object, [directives])  This stores an object. It can be used to update or create an object. This returns a promise that may resolve to the object after it has been saved. 

add(object, [directives])  This creates an object, and throws an error if the object already exists. This should return a promise for the newly created object.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As GibboK mentioned Directives are object containing information about creating and updating stored objects.

The valid properties are:

`id - String|Number?` - id is used to as identity for new object. Used in `add()` only.

`beforeId - String?` - the new created or update object to be place before the id mentined in the property.

`overwrite - Boolean?` - indicates that the object should or should not overwrite an existing object.

The documentation can be found in the code "dstore\Store.js" Store.PutDirective. There is also another property `parent` which is not used.

The directive for `dstore\Rest` has additional property `header - Object?` which would contain the header information for the request.

You may have to look at the type of store, you are using to get the complete documentation of the valid object you can pass as `[directives]`.

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> Directives passed to put() and add() handlers for guiding the update
>   and creation of stored objects.

Unfortunately, there is very limited documentation about `directives`.